# Can't evaluate true / false return from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement a ReCaptcha with AJAX to verify it so that I can stop the page from submitting if the ReCaptcha fails.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
function verify_recaptcha(){
jQuery.post(
    'verify_recaptcha.php',
    {
        recaptcha_challenge_field: jQuery('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(),
        recaptcha_response_field: jQuery('#recaptcha_response_field').val()
    },
    function(data){
        if(data == "true"){
            alert("ReCaptcha Verified");
        }
        else{
            alert(data);
        }
    }
   );
}
```

And the contents of verify_recaptcha.php

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "-- my private key --";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                              $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                              $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                              $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
  echo "false";
} else {
  echo "true";
}
?>
```

The problem is that my test Alert is showing "true" if the recaptcha verifies (and false if it doesn't), which I don't think should be possible. It should evaluate data == "true" in that if statement and display "ReCaptcha Verified".

Most anything I search on the subject the problem is that people are trying to return a value out of the AJAX call, which I know I can't do and am not doing here.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the return result (using something like your browser tools, or Fiddler 2) and make sure the return value is what you expect.

Comment: Try `if($.trim(data) === "true")` or remove `?>` from PHP file

Comment: In `function(data)` add `console.log(data);` in order to check the return value...

Comment: A. Wolff got it. For some reason there was a space at the end of the "true" string coming from the server. Trimming the data worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reframed your code a bit. Try,**

**PHP:**

```
...
...

$json = array();

if (!$resp->is_valid) 
   $json['result'] = true;
else 
   $json['result'] = false;

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($json);
```

**JS:**

```
...
...

jQuery.post(
'verify_recaptcha.php',
{
    recaptcha_challenge_field: jQuery('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(),
    recaptcha_response_field: jQuery('#recaptcha_response_field').val()
})
.done(function(response){

    console.log(response);

    if(response.result == true)
    {
        // Entered captcha is correct
    }
    else
    {
        // Entered captcha is incorrect
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**

1) Always return boolean **`true/false`** and not in form of string.
2) Use **`.done()`**. Won't make much difference from your code, but **`.done()`** make your ajax call code much **clear**.
3) Always open your **`console`** and try printing objects and see the output if it is what you are expecting.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as it solves the problem and I agree with all of your points. Just for the sake of anyone stumbling across this question later, the actual problem with the code was that there was a space being appended to the "true" return. Returning a boolean true/flase is definitely the answer.

Comment: Also, pretty sure there's a missing ')' in there. I'll fix it.